# How to find the index in button to modal Reactjs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, reactjs, web

so im having Difficulty on passing the index from button to button so here is my code 
the first one is the render loop that shows all my rows and its button the button at the delete part is calling the index from the row

```
    renderItem(d, i) {
  return <tr key={i} >
    <td> {d.Employee_ID} </td>
    <td>{d.Employee_Name}</td>
    <td>{d.Address }</td> 
    <td><center><button className ="btn btn-info" onClick={this.handleOnclick.bind(this,  d.Employee_ID, d.Employee_Name, d.Address , d.Department)}   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UpdateEmployee">Edit</button></center></td>
    <td><center><button className ='btn btn-danger'  onClick={this.handleOnclick.bind(this,  d.Employee_ID , d.Employee_Name,i)} data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DeleteEmployee"> Delete</button></center></td>


         </tr>
}
```

this is where it proceed to my modal

```
 {/*Delete*/}
           <div className="modal fade" id="DeleteEmployee" role="dialog">
           <div className="modal-dialog">
             <div className="modal-content">
                <div className="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 className="modal-title">Delete Employee</h4>
                </div>


                  <div className="container">
                  <div className="modal-body">
                        Are you sure you want to delete {this.state.Employee_Name}?
                  </div>
                  </div>
                <div className="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" className ="btn btn-danger"  data-dismiss="modal" onClick={this.deleteEmployee.bind(this, this.state.Employee_ID ,this.state.i)}/>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</button>
              </div>


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

but the onclick on my modal can't see the index please help me because it always delete the first row

```
deleteEmployee(id, index) {
  jQuery.support.cors = true;
    fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/DeleteEmployeeDetail/'+ id, {
         method: 'GET'
  }).then(function(response) {
     // history.go(0);
      var jsonReturnedValue = [...this.state.jsonReturnedValue];
      this.setState({jsonReturnedValue})
  }).catch(function(err) {
    // Error :(
  });
    this.state.jsonReturnedValue.splice(index, 1)
    this.setState({})
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `but the onclick on my modal can't see the index`? please clarify. Have you tried logging whether the `deleteEmployee` receives the correct parameters?

Comment: the modal cant see the "i" (or which i call the index) it edits perfectly when refreshed but when the ajax delete it only deletes the first row but when refreshed it deletes the correct row you deleted

Comment: @ickyrr the "i" in key={i} i passed it on the button but the modal's button cant read it

Comment: Do you have a repo for this? I would like to take a look at how you structured your code. I have a lot of questions but it's much better to see the code itself.

Comment: @ickyrr what is repo?

Comment: github repository, that contains all your code, not fragments... the problem maybe in the way, you render items. If you use index from array as `key` this is your first problem

Comment: as @Lojka said, what I meant was `github` repository. So you can share your code and it will be very helpful.

Comment: i dont have a github account... can i send it in other way? @ickyrr

Comment: you can write full code here, or create github account, it is free.

Comment: @Lojka i dont know how to use that -_-